# Python Flask Rest API - Is it possible to have separate logs for each request

Tags: python, flask

I have a Python Flask rest api. Each time a user creates a request.get call, is it possible to have a separate log file ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but I think there are better solutions.

If you really wanted to do this, it would look something like the following:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index_page():
    # Provide a unique filename
    with open('%s.txt' % (flask.session['_id'])) as log:
        log.write('Log entry here.')
    return 'Hello World!'
```

I think a better thing to do though, would be to have one consolidated log, with a unique identifier for each request.